# Scan and read data from beacon (EM Microelectronic : EMBC02)

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I'm trying to create an Android app that scans the beacons using BLE and retrieve data from it, so I'm gonna to use this library:
 [Android Beacon Library](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library)

Any idea how to use it and especially how to scan only **EM Microelectronic EMBC02** beacons ?

I tried to use the 2 sample [here](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html) but can't always find my beacons. It's mentioned that I should use this method `setBeaconLayout()` but I don't know how.

```
    // To detect proprietary beacons, you must add a line like below corresponding to your beacon
    // type.  Do a web search for "setBeaconLayout" to get the proper expression.
    // beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
    //        setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=beac,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That beacon model uses the iBeacon layout. You must configure the layout string into the library.   You can find the layout strings here: https://beaconlayout.wordpress.com